# How to create circle using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, model-view-controller

I wannt to create circle Like [image]

this will done using chart api but i don't want to use chartapi
Can any one help me.

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery SVG to drw whatever you want : http://keith-wood.name/svg.html